# How to set custom layout on CheckBox preferences in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I have developed an application that has one preferences activity for application setting so I want know about can we set custom graphics layout (XML) on preferences layout like CheckBox has own color Button while check and unchecked and list has own color if possible then how?

Answer (score 0):

create XML in Drawable with button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_on"/>
 <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_off"/>
 <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_on"/>
<item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_off"/>
</selector>
```

radio_on

[image: radio_on button]

radio_off

[image]

Put both image in drawable folder radio_on.png and radio_off.png

Now at Your Radio Button Write This

```
android:button="@drawable/button"
```

Answer (score 0):

custom_checkbox_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+android:id/checkbox" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false" android:button="@drawable/button"/>
```

After that in the CheckBoxPreference set android:widgetLayout="@layout/custom_checkbox_layout"